# Mamp won't start MySQL server after install?

Tags: mamp

I only just installed MAMP and MySQL won't start. I have seen fixes like deleting ib_logfiles, but I don't have those files (I think because I only just installed it and have never opened it before).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start it with your terminal?

> mysql.server start

Worked fine for me.

Comment: "command note found". sorry I am new, but I tried changing directory to applications (where it is saved) and I still get the same alert, adding "cd mamp" and I get "No such file or directory"